# Expecting Number (Average Temperature) but Getting Null

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to pull the average temperature of two stations, *JFK* and *La Guardia*, for June 2020, but I am getting `Null`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  AVG(temp) AS avg_temp
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2020
WHERE
  temp IN
 (
  SELECT
    AVG(temp)
  FROM
    bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2020
  WHERE
    stn="744860" -- JFK
   AND date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
 ) 
 OR temp IN 
 (
  SELECT
    AVG(temp)
  FROM
    bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2020
  WHERE
    stn="725030" -- La Guardia
   AND date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
 )
;
```

Comment: Try running the the subquery separately and see if there's any results. If any of the subquery return `NULL`, remove `AVG()` aggregation and re-run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That SQL seems unnecessarily complicated, why not just use:

```
SELECT
    AVG(temp)
  FROM
    bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2020
  WHERE
   ( stn="744860" or stn="725030") 
   AND date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
```